# MongoDB insert conundrum

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB so I am hoping someone can explain to me a simple concept with MongoDB which is inserting and retrieving.

1) Is MongoDB able to take in just any data or does it have to be a string? For example, I have a variable called `Variable` and it is holding a string. Can I do

```
emp_rec1 = {
        "name":"Mr.Geek",
        "eid":24,
        "location":"delhi"
        }
```

But instead of `location:"delhi"`, can I have `location:variable` or does it have to be in the string format?
Thanks!

2) If this works, how would I be able to retrieve what I stored in the location?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores BSON objects, that is Binary JSON. A specification can be found here:

[BSON](http://bsonspec.org)

This means it works on JSON documents. In JSON, it is a representation of objects, arrays and the like. A variable has only meaning in a programing language like Javacript or Typescript. What would your variable mean if I was to read it in my REST service?
It cant have a meaning in JSON as it is would be impossible to give it context, an initialising value or any other operation.

JSON describes data structures only. I read it in a service say and assign it to variables at that point. Why do you need to store a name in a JSON object?